# How to setup SBT dependency for scala code that is located in same directory as Build.scala

Tags: scala, sbt

Our project features a kind of adhoc "plugin" that reads csv files and stuffs the contents into a database.

This code is defined in /project/DataMigrate.scala

We had our own poorly implemented version of a CSV parser that isn't up to the task anymore so I tried to add this https://github.com/tototoshi/scala-csv to the libraryDependencies in /project/Build.scala but that did not make it importable from DataMigrate.scala. I also tried putting the library dependency in /project/build.sbt as I read something about "Build definition of a build definition", but that did not seem to help either.

Is it at all possible to add dependencies for code that lives in /project?

Answer (score 0):

SBT is recursive, so just as you can define dependencies and settings of the actual project in `[something].sbt` or `project/[something].scala` you can define dependencies and settings of the projects project (any ad hoc plugins etc) in `project/[something].sbt` or `project/project/[something].scala`

Comment: But are all the files in main/project part of "the project's project"? When I add the dependency to libraryDependencies in main/project/build.sbt it is not importable in the main/project/DataMigrate.scala file. I started suspecting that main/project/build.sbt is the "build definition for the build definition" but maybe the build definition only includes a combination of the .sbt file and the related Build.scala file?

Comment: That should work, so for example, you create the plugin project/MyGitPlugin.scala that needs JGit, then you would need to add a jgit dependency in either project/[something].sbt or project/project/[something].scala, if it doesn't, in what way does it not work, project load error?

Comment: Yes, this sounds quite close to what I am attempting to do. First of all Intellij allows me to find the CSVReader object I am attempting to use, but after it is included the import line is shown red with the error "Cannot resolve symbol". Secondly, when running sbt I get an error already about the package namespace of the CSVReader.

Comment: Have you refreshed intellij and reloaded sbt when trying again? If not this is the reason why you are getting error, SBT has got an immutable representation of the build in memory which is not automatically updated when you change the project, Intellij has the same problem but with the need to generate an intellij-native representation of the project.

Comment: I've been trying almost anything I can think of (including invalidate caches/restart) when testing in sbt and I get an error I usually press q to quit and then rerun after I randomly change something. So I don't think this should be the problem.

Comment: You know, this answer is documented in the sbt documentation, and yet it doesn't seem to be true. I also cannot add dependencies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31192904/adding-dependency-to-classpath-of-build-scala