# How to add library dependency to classpath of Build.scala?

Tags: sqlite, scala, jdbc, sbt

I'm trying to use the [sqlite-jdbc driver](https://github.com/xerial/sqlite-jdbc) in my `Build.scala` to generate a sqlite db with some necessary tables before compilation. This is what I wrote to achieve that:

```
compile in Compile <<= (compile in Compile) map { result =>
  val sqliteDb = file("my_sqlite.db")
  if (!sqliteDb.exists()) {
    val connection = DriverManager.getConnection(s"jdbc:sqlite:${sqliteDb.getAbsolutePath}")
    val statement = connection.prepareStatement("create table EXAMPLE ( ... );")
    statement.execute()
    statement.close()
    connection.close()
  }
  result
}
```

That's all well and good, but when I run `compile` I get this error:

```
[error] (my-project/compile:compile) java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlite:/Users/2rs2ts/src/my-project/my_sqlite.db
```

Now that's a bit frustrating since I thought I could add that dependency to `Build.scala`'s classpath by creating a recursive project. My directory structure looks like this:

```
my-project/
  project/
    Build.scala
    build.sbt
    project/
      build.sbt
```

And `my-project/project/project/build.sbt` looks like this:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.xerial" % "sqlite-jdbc" % "3.8.10.1"
```

*Edit*: I also put that line in `my-project/project/build.sbt` and it did not resolve my issue.

So... what did I do wrong? I need this dependency on the classpath in order to get the sqlite driver to work.

Comment: Regardless of the error messages you're facing, you should *not* do that kind of work at compile time. Compilation time is probably long enough to skip it as often as possible, and you're adding up more work to it.

Don't!

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I'm trying to guarantee that the file exists and has the correct tables before I do anything with my project. That includes: running it, running its tests, and packaging it in different formats.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So... what did I do wrong?

You went two steps too far. Move that `libraryDependencies` from `my-project/project/project/build.sbt` to `my-project/project/build.sbt` that way it will be available in `my-project/project/Build.scala`.

Comment: I found out the solution. Normally there is a `static` block in the dependency's `Driver` implementation that registers it with the `DriverManager` but for some reason it doesn't get executed until I actually refer to it in `Build.scala`. Bit of a quirk about how this sqlite driver is supposed to work... I don't understand why the `static` block wasn't getting executed but at least my issue is resolved as it were.